# Automatic generation of changeset / commit message (preferably for Mercurial)

Tags: git, mercurial, diff, commit, tortoisehg

Almost all of my commit messages include a list of files modified, then list of functions/classes in each file modified and then description of what has been changed. Something like:

```
file1.py:
 - function_lala(): changed something to something
 - function_lala2():...
file2.py:
....
```

Having to manually type each time those file names and functions is kind of annoying. I understand, that these informations could be obtained from parsing the diff output and then a skeleton of the commit message could be generated, which I would only have to fill with relevant information.

Are you aware of any tool for such commit messages skeleton generation? I am using TortoiseHG with Mercurial, but I guess I could adapt from some different system.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I customize the 'commit message file' generated by \`hg commit\`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4291826/how-do-i-customize-the-commit-message-file-generated-by-hg-commit)

Comment: This still seems mainly to be a topic of research: Neural-Machine-Translation-Based Commit Message
Generation: How Far Are We? [https://xin-xia.github.io/publication/ase181.pdf]

Comment: Thanks. I am close. I generated hg diff parser which is called by prestatus hook when hg status is issued. However... I wonder if there is any way to call it and put it into TortoiseHG commit pane. I have prestatus hook but I don't think thg uses status at any stage.

Comment: Why though? The commits already contain _which files_ have changed. The diff shows _what_ has changed in the files.

Comment: To know to which function in which file the specific part of the commit message applies.